# line return on white space using CSS

Tags: css

I'm using a CMS that adds a title to the menu on the home page. This is in the form of Li.

If my page title has two words 'Hello World' I want a line return between the two words, so the words appear on two lines. How can i do this ?

I've tried combinations of word-wrap, white-space but doesnt force of white space.
Help appreciated. Thanks

Update : Using SharePoint and cannot add tags to title.

```
    .s4-tn li.static > .menu-item {
    color:white;

    border:0px none transparent;
    background-color:transparent;
    height:38px;
    padding:7px 10px 5px;   
    font-size:1.2em;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 1px solid white;  
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:100;        
}

.menu-item-text {
    width:6em;
    background:lime;
    height:30px;
    white-space:pre-line;

}
```

Browser rendered HTML CODE:

```
<div class="menu horizontal menu-horizontal">
        <ul class="root static">
            <li class="static"><a class="static menu-item" href="/expense" accesskey="1"><span class="additional-background"><span class="menu-item-text">Expense Form</span></span></a></li><li class="static">
```

Comment: Where is your code? Where,oh where is the code?

Comment: Please provide the code of same to give us a better understanding.

Comment: I don't know a viable css-way to make a whitespace behave like a linebreak except when the width isn't sufficient or you convert the whitespace explicitely into a `<br>`.

Comment: basically this is a CMS question as you need to alter how the HTML is produced - if it's Drupal search under THEMING otherwise we need more information. -1 as not enough info is provided to answer the question.

Comment: If no viable option in CSS, can this be done through javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"Hello<br /> world"`

Comment: the user has to type that which might not be what the OP wants and also the CMS might escape HTML-stuff.

Comment: maybe his CMS doesn't let him enter html in the title field. (most probably)

Comment: Hi My CMS is SharePoint, I cannot add tags in the title but can adjust the CSS.